# nmap -v -p 515 127.0.0.1

Tags: printing

After running the following command:

```
nmap -v -p 515 127.0.0.1
```

Ubuntu Show this Message:

```
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
515/tcp closed printer
```

How To Change **Closed** to **Open** ?

Answer (score 0):

Port `515/tcp` is the `line printer spooler` port. You could run a print spooler to listen to port 515, but....

The modern, Ubuntu way is to use CUPS (Common Unix Printing System), which listens to the Internet Printing Protocol on port `631/tcp`. Read `man cups`. Administer CUPS with a browser pointer to `http://localhost:631`

And, an easier way to see what's listening (or not) to a port is with `lsof` (and you get more information):

```
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:515 -i tcp:631
[sudo] password for w3: 
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
cupsd   17693 root   10u  IPv4 4833522      0t0  TCP *:ipp (LISTEN)
cupsd   17693 root   11u  IPv6 4833523      0t0  TCP *:ipp (LISTEN)
```